# Open file - additional hidden information

Tags: c#

When I want to open a file with its default application I simply use:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    FileName = filePath,
    WorkingDirectory = new FileInfo(filePath).DirectoryName
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But there is a problem:
When I play an MP4 file from a directory within the *windows explorer*, the file is opened using Microsoft Movies & TV. But also the app gets information about other files in the same directory because there is the possibility to go to the next video. This only works when I am in the given directory inside the *windows explorer* when opening. When I use for example *quick access* to open the file I cannot go to other files although there are other videos inside the directory.

I created a blank console app to print all the parameters and then I opened an MP4 file with it:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (string s in args)
        Console.WriteLine(s);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But no matter where I open this app from (within the directory, quick access), it always outputs:

```
1

D:\Videos\Video1.mp4
```

So the same parameters lead to different app behavior.

So where does this additional information come from and how to add it using *Process.Start*? Is there something registered within the registry which parameters should be passed to a given app? If so, how to get this information?

**Edit: UWP FileActivatedEventArgs test try**

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args) {
    var files = args.NeighboringFilesQuery.GetFilesAsync(0, args.NeighboringFilesQuery.GetItemCountAsync().GetResults()).GetResults();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var file in files) {
        sb.AppendLine(file.Name);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Videos\files.txt", sb.ToString());

    base.OnFileActivated(args);
}
```

Comment: Not helpful but I wanted to comment I noticed the same thing, some applications somehow get information from the file sorting in Windows Explorer. For example, while using the default image viewer, if you searched and just got one file from a folder with many files, you cannot go back or forward. If you sort the folder by date, when seeing a picture you can move forward and it's also ordered by date. I look forward to an answer to this.

Comment: @CodeCaster Edit: I added the working directory to the start info. Nothing changed.

Comment: Probably has to do with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs.neighboringfilesquery?view=winrt-19041#Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_FileActivatedEventArgs_NeighboringFilesQuery, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onfileactivated?view=winrt-19041

Comment: Okay, if so then there is the question of how to set the query when starting the process

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried to test it, but I have no experience with UWP. I created a blank UWP app and added the code of the Edit. Also I set a file assoziation for .mp4. But the app never starts. Neither when opening the file nor when just opening the .exe

Comment: @CodeCaster Okay, you were right. I had to change GetResults() to GetAwaiter().GetResult and I had to run the app before opening the file and then I was able to debug and the query contained all the files. Now is the question is there a way to pass this query when starting the process

Comment: My guess would be that this list is passed through a named pipe to the UWP framework which launches the app, not sure how you could manually invoke that, not sure if it's documented.

Comment: Maybe some help? I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iapplicationactivationmanager-activateforfile) but I don't know if this will work

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to call an external process and send it the neighbor files? Or have your program be called from the explorer and be able to browser such files?

Comment: @Andrew I want to open any file. If the default application associated with this file is a UWP app I want to SEND the neighboring files.

Comment: So your program kind of tries to emulate opening the file from Windows Explorer, right?

Comment: So any new ideas?